# ACRA: What Happens When No Internet Connection Is Present?

Tags: android, acra

With ACRA, what happens to the error report when the user did not have internet at the time?

I have researched and could not find a direct answer. I found that it does store the reports on SD card.

Are the reports automatically sent once the internet is present? 
Or do I need to program this functionality to send reports that could not be sent?

I tried to experiment with this on AVD but even when I press F8 or put it in Airplane Mode, seems to be an connection still....sigh

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reports are written to disk.

When either the app restarts or another error occurs ACRA will attempt to send all outstanding reports.

Don't stress too much about it. Error reports are statistical by nature. Some you will get, others you won't (for a variety of reasons). As long as you getting a reasonably good sample you will be able to respond to problems and improve your app.

Comment: but does it requires internet to send reports?

Comment: Of course. It can't magically wish the reports to your server. At some point it will need a connection.